# Assigning each column to corresponding checkbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, checkbox, sqlite

I have 33 checkboxes which is a bus seats with their own seat number, also i have 33 columns in my bus_seats table. In my form and database everything is set up. But I am stuck at assigning values from sql to checkboxes. I can do it manually setting

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM bus_seats WHERE sefer_id = 1";
using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connect))
{
    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["5"]) == 1)
        {
            checkBox5.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, reader["5"] is my 5th seat in sql table, and checkBox5 is my 5th seat in my form. I don't want to assign them manually and create huge "if" statements. Is there any easy way to compare column values and checkbox values? In my code **reader["5"] == 1** means 5th Seat taken by a women(pink), 2 means its taken by a man(blue), 0 means empty(gray). I am trying to colorize checkbox background color by their sql values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your textboxes are in a container use that container id otherwise use the form id.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM bus_seats WHERE sefer_id = 1";
using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connect))
{
     SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         var seat = reader["seatNumber"].ToString();
         var chk = string.Format("checkBox{0}", seat);

         if (reader["seatTaken"].ToString() == "True")
         {
             ((CheckBox)form1.FindControl(chk)).BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't have seatNumber column in my table, i have 1 to 33 columns like this
http://i.imgur.com/3eTI2Kz.jpg

Comment: You are going about this all wrong. You don't need a column for each seat, just add a seatNumber column and remove 1 through 14. Your table really only needs 3 columns for this: The primary key (someID), seatNumber (can be a string), and isTaken (bit). Then you can add additional columns as needed for things like who is in the seat, the color, etc. Adding a column for each seat is going to give you an issue if a second row is ever entered.

Comment: Nice, i got it working. By the way it was a winforms application so replaced Findcontrol with this
CheckBox chx = this.Controls.Find(chk, true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;